# Is it possible to track users and send their locations to a sever in the background on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, service, background, location

I keep reading conflicting things on doing this. I want to create an app that matches users based on location by sending their location to my server every x minutes to see if there are any other users nearby, but the users obviously won't have the app open all day and will not be able to see if there are any other users nearby unless they both have the app open in the foreground. For instance, if I open the app in the morning and then it goes to the background, my server will have my last location as wherever I was when I had the app in the foreground in the morning, but I want my server to know wherever the user is every x number of minutes and they would obviously consent to this kind of monitoring. Proximity would be very importance, hence the need for accurate and continual location updates.

Is this type of app even possible or would I have problems with the background post requests?

I was thinking that a simple solution might be to simply track all the data in the background and then submit all the coordinates that were collected in the background whenever the user brings it to the foreground, but this would  not allow people to see other users that are nearby until  the other users bring their apps to the foreground and submit where they've been as well.

Basically, if two people are in the same location, I'd like the person with the app in the foreground (person A) to be able to see the person with the app in the background (person B), even if person B hasn't had the app in the foreground for a while. I'm thinking this will require a timer and background location/network activity, but need to know how to go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not possible. When you put your app in background your app will be in idel state. Hence you cannot track the location of the users who have kept the app in background. Maye be you can have some predefined location sets alrdy. So that when ever other users (A-Z) come across that location thet will notify the actual user.

Comment: Since iOS 4, apps may run, in a limited manner, in the background if they provide location, audio or voip services and also if they access external devices.  See UIBackgroundModes https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html  and http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios.  iOS 7 will enhance backgrounded apps by occasionally calling them to perfrom short tasks.      All this being said, polling location while in the background will drain the devices battery rapidly and should be used sparingly.